# Improve the performance of loading of a huge JSON in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, json, performance

I have a situation where I need to load a huge JSON object (4.5GB open and 400MB compressed) from S3.
Currently, it is done with streaming similar to the following code:

```
let result = S3.getObject(getBatchParams)
               .createReadStream()
               .pipe(gunzipExtractor)
               .pipe(JSONStream.parse())
               .on('data', objectData => {return resolve(objectData)}
```

Loading the JSON takes several minutes.
I'm looking for ways to reduce this time.
Stuff as different loading methods, libraries, V8 GC flags, or any other technic.
The current loading process is CPU bound (the Node process is 100% CPU during the whole loading process)
I'm aware that loading such a json is a bad idea, to begin with :)

Comment: First need to figure out where your bottleneck is. With a CPU at 100%, it's most likely the decompression that's the culprit, so you could try looking into more efficient decompression libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested a version reading from a local file without compression and the times are similar so I'm assuming most of the time is spent on allocating the huge object. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: It seems like you'd be a lot better off parsing the JSON as a stream and adding it to a database as you go, not attempting to keep the entire thing in memory all the time.   Then, from then on, use it from the database, not from the JSON.  4.5GB of data likely belongs in a database, not in a single Javascript object.  Giant amounts of data in memory is not something Javascript is particularly good at as just the process of initially parsing it will likely consume a lot of memory and lead to a lot of GC dealing with all the temporary strings involved in parsing.